# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str error appears while parsing xml

Tags: python-3.x, xml, parsing

I tried to write a parses for my device. But I can't undestood where I made mistake, because I got the error:

```
print(value2['@id'])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

My code you may see below:

```
import requests
import xmltodict 

url = 'http://192.168.1.8:8060/query/apps'
text = requests.get(url).text
#content = """
#<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
#<apps>
#<app id="31012" type="menu" #version="2.0.53">Vudu Movie &amp; #TV Store</app>
#</apps>
#"""
text = text.split('\n')
text = text[1:]
text = ''.join(text)
data = xmltodict.parse(text)
data = dict(data)

for key1, value1 in data.items():
  for key2, value2 in value1.items():
    print(value2['@id'])
    print(value2['@type'])
    print(value2['#text'])
```

Could anyone help me with it, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests
import xmltodict 

url = 'http://192.168.1.8:8060/query/apps'
text = requests.get(url).text
#content = """
#<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
#<apps>
#<app id="31012" type="menu" #version="2.0.53">Vudu Movie &amp; #TV Store</app>
#</apps>
#"""
text = text.split('\n')
text = text[1:]
text = ''.join(text)
data = xmltodict.parse(text)
data = dict(data)

for key1, value1 in data.items():
    for key2, value2 in value1.items():
        if isinstance(value2, list):
            for item in value2:
                print(item['@id'])
                print(item['@type'])
                print(item['#text'])
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).